# ¿como sumar 2 columnas de una tabla y comparar el resultado con otra columna en una clausula where con eloquent? laravel 8

Tags: laravel

estoy sumando 2 columnas de mi tabla `products` **quantity_stock** y **quantity_inventory** para comparar el resultado de esta suma con la columna **min_supply_quantity** tengo esta consulta SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE quantity_stock + quantity_inventory <= min_supply_quantity;
```

Siguiendo la lógica con eloquent creí que sería algo así:

```
 Product::select('*')->where('quantity_stock  + quantity_inventory','<=','min_supply_quantity')->get();
```

de esta manera no encuentra las columnas quantity_stock y quantity_inventory::

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'quantity_stock + quantity_inventory)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `quantity_stock + quantity_inventory)` <= min_supply_quantity)
```

Itenté usando Raw de muchas maneras, pero me sale que hay un error de sintaxis puesto que no dimino el uso del Raw ¿de que manera puedo hacer esta consulta??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo mediante el método [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw) pasando el string de la condición como único argumento de la siguiente forma:

```
 Product::whereRaw('quantity_stock  + quantity_inventory <= min_supply_quantity')->get();
```

De esta manera en lugar de buscar una columna cuyo nombre sea: *la sumatoria de ambas columnas*, interpretará dicha operación.

Finalmente tampoco necesitas indicar en el método `select` que recupere todas las columnas con el comodín `*`, de hecho solo debería ser empleado cuando requieres indicar [un conjunto específico de columnas.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#specifying-a-select-clause)

Comment: Gracias @BetaM siempre confiable :)